# Flutter UI - Customized TextFormField Transition Like Uber Application

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

[image: TextFormField][1]]

When user clicks on a text field, that text field should be transit in to a new page and you can make changes in that page. This feature is available in the Uber App (Under Edit Profile). How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

[image]Playing around with [TextField onTap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onTap.html) property, [TextField readOnly](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/readOnly.html) property and [Hero](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Hero-class.html) class should give us something pragmatic or close.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Hero(
            tag: "input",
            child: Material(
              child: TextField(
                readOnly: true,
                // make TextField readable only
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                keyboardAppearance: Brightness.light,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    fillColor: Color(0xFFF4F4F4),
                    hintText: "Name here",
                    filled: true),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(_createRoute());
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Route _createRoute() {
  return PageRouteBuilder(
    fullscreenDialog: true,
    opaque: false,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 700),
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => const Page2(),
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      const begin = Offset(0.0, 1.0);
      const end = Offset.zero;
      const curve = Curves.ease;

      var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));

      return SlideTransition(
        position: animation.drive(tween),
        child: child,
      );
    },
  );
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: const Hero(
        tag: "input",
        child: Material(
          child: TextField(
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
            keyboardAppearance: Brightness.light,
            autofocus: true,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                fillColor: Color(0xFFF4F4F4),
                hintText: "Name here",
                filled: true),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }[![Schreenshot][4]][4]
}
```